# How does the SELECT query work on multiple columns without using comma in between column names?

Tags: mysql, database, alias, rdbms, select-query

I'm studying **SQL** from **w3schools SQL Tutorial**

While studying the chapter **SQL Aliases** I come across following query :

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address+', '+City+', '+PostalCode+', '+Country AS Address
FROM Customers;
```

If you observe closely the query is fetching data from multiple columns, attaches the data from different columns with comma and show the data under aliased column name **Address**

If you want to see the working demo please go to the URL

```
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column2&ss=-1
```

When we write normal query without alias for fetching data from different columns of a table we separate the column names with comma as follows :

```
SELECT CustomerName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country FROM Customers;
```

My doubt is as there are no commas have been used in a SELECT query for fetching data from different columns then how does it working?

The existing commas you see from the first query are for the purpose of connecting strings in output only.

Would someone please clear my doubt.

It would be better if someone could explain me from **MySQL database** point of view as I'm concerned with **MySQL database system** only.

Thank You.

Comment: This will not work in MySQL, since in MySQL `+` operator cannot be used for string concatenation. But in general, the 2nd field is an expression, in which you concatenate the values of several fields with some string literals (`', '`)

Comment: `I'm studying SQL from w3schools SQL Tutorial` - please don't study from w3schools. Also, for MySQL to concatenate, use it's `CONCAT` function. `SELECT CustomerName, CONCAT(Address, ', ', City, ', ', PostalCode, ', ', Country) AS Address`.

Comment: @Mjh : What's wrong with w3schools tutorials? I don't understand why many of the people are against w3schools!!! They are easy to understand, to the point and better than those lengthy manuals and other such tutorials.

Comment: @user2839497 I didn't explain, that's my fault. What's wrong with them is that they're not correct or true, and contain many intricate false details that lead people to the wrong path and to wrong conclusions. Yes, they're easy to understand and are better than official manuals, I concede that. Using a name such as `w3schools` it can falsely lead you to a conclusion they're an authority similar to `w3.org`, which is basically what they play at. to attract people and then they provide subpar, incorrect tutorials which DO teach people but only up to a POINT. Be careful while using.

Comment: @Mjh : Thanks for your explanation but they continuously update their tutorials. I'm agree with you that 2-3 years back the quality of their tutorials was very poor but now the scenario is different. They cover almost everything necessary for quick learning. That's my own experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are two different operators. The server parser recognizes an operator lets say , or +. And handles it appropriately. Column value is evaluated for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

user2839497! You can view this as a formula, just like a mathematical formula. So, just like you can `SELECT COL1 + COL2 AS TOTAL_SALES...` you can also append strings together in a formula.

BTW, I think I should add that the plus sign (+) doesn't work for appending strings in every database. Some have other syntaxes or ways to do this. (For example, I believe Informix or Oracle uses two pipes (||) to do this)